# Is it possible to implement direct jumps (i.e., GOTO) in Rust?

Tags: optimization, rust, goto

I'm exploring optimizations for the [HVM](https://github.com/kindelia/hvm), a parallel functional runtime written in Rust. The way it works by spawning several threads, and then having each one busy on a [main work loop](https://github.com/Kindelia/HVM/blob/V2/src/runtime.rs#L1378) where tasks are popped and executed. It works more or less like this:

```
// Modes
enum Mode {
  Visiting, // visits a node
  Reducing, // applies a rewrite rule
  Fetching, // pops a local task
  Stealing, // steals a global task
}

// Main loop
loop {
  match mode {
    Visiting => { ... do stuff ... }
    Reducing => { ... do stuff ... }
    Fetching => { ... do stuff ... }
    Stealing => { ... do stuff ... }
  }
}

// Change mode with:
mode = Mode::Visiting;
continue 'main;
```

I expected Rust's compiler to optimize that to a `goto`, but, to my surprise, it doesn't. In an attempt to improve the situation, I've replaced the `Mode` enum by two booleans, and adjusted my loop as follows:

```
// Modes
let mut a : bool;
let mut b : bool;

// Main loop
loop {
  if a {
    if b {
      ... do stuff ...
    } else {
      ... do stuff ...
    }
  } else {
    if b {
      ... do stuff ...
    } else {
      ... do stuff ...
    }
  }
}

// Change mode with:
a = true;
b = true;
continue 'main;
```

To my surprise, this small change resulted in a ~15% improvement on the overall performance of HVM's runtime! This is still not ideal though. If I was in C, I'd just have labels, and jump via `GOTO`. My question is: can I change my Rust code in a way that will let the compiler optimize to the expected jumping code? I.e., something like this?

```
// Main loop:
loop {
  'visiting { ... do stuff ... }
  'reducing { ... do stuff ... }
  'fetching { ... do stuff ... }
  'stealing { ... do stuff ... }
}

// Change mode with:
goto 'visiting
```

Comment: Do you think you could build a more minimal example on Godbolt, so we could compare asm?

Comment: Just some musings: Have you tried using `match (work, init)` instead of the `if` tree? And have you tried using an `if ... else if ...` sequence with the enum? Those experiments could help eliminate the variable of using `match` vs conditionals.

Comment: @PitaJ using enums perform the same as `if else`, as long as I use two enums with 2 constructors each. Didn't try `match (work init)` yet, it might improve how the code looks, at least. I'll try reproduce a minimal example later.

Comment: If I try to reproduce this, [LLVM does generate a jump table](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Ehh4job65).